# Send array string with post httpClient ionic

Tags: web-services, ionic-framework, http-post, httpclient, arrayobject

I want to send params and recive another ones, and I got an issue with my method to sending these parametres (array of string and string) with post method of HttpClient in ionic.

The error (isn't the CORS Security, cause i run with my device too and i got the same issue):

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:64411/getLabels' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

My code from ionic:

```
var apiURL = 'http://localhost:64411/';
pathGetLabels: string = apiURL + 'getLabels';

constructor(public http: HttpClient, public material: MaterialProvider, public hp : Http) {
     }
loadLabels(lbls: any){
        return this.http.post(this.pathGetLabels, lbls ,Language);}
```

The array got no problems and this is:

```
Array(6)
0: "USER"
1: "Password"
2: "SaveAccount"
3: "lbl_login"
4: "ForgetPass"
5: "Register"
length: 6
```

And the code of Web Service Api Rest:

```
[Route("getLabels/{paramOne}/{paramTwo}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage getLabels([FromBody]string[] paramOne, string idL)
        {
            var labels = LanguagesRepository.GetLabels(paramOne, idL);
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, labels);

            return response;
        }
```

I tried to do these things to and I got the same issue:

```
return this.http.get(this.pathGetLabels+ JSON.stringify(lbls) +"/"+Language);
return this.http.get(this.pathGetLabels+ JSON.stringify(lbls), Language);
```